# Vivado HLS Synthesize error

Tags: vivado-hls

I'm currently trying to do some project on Vivado HLS. However, I got an error as shown in the title during synthesis. However, this error appears:

> error:** invalid operands to binary expression ('double' and 'datau32' (aka 'ap_axiu<32, 2, 5, 6>')) imgOut= (0.2126*Imgin[coord] + 0.7152*Imgin[coord+1] + 0.0722*Imgin[coord+2])

This is my HLS code:

```
#include "core.h"

void imgreading(hls::stream<datau32> &inStream, datau32 Imgin[imagesize])
{
    for(int i=0;i<imagesize;i++)
    {
        Imgin[i]=(datau32)inStream.read();
    }
}

void resize_half(hls::stream<datau32> &inStream, hls::stream<datau32> &outStream)
{
#pragma HLS INTERFACE axis port=inStream
#pragma HLS INTERFACE axis port=outStream
#pragma HLS INTERFACE s_axilite port=return bundle=CRTL_BUS
    datau32 Imgin[imagesize];
    imgreading (inStream,Imgin);
    datau32 imgOut;
    int coord=0;


#pragma HLS DATAFLOW
    for (int a=0; a<240; a++) {
        for(int b=0; b<320; b++){
#pragma HLS PIPELINE II=1
            coord=6*(a*640+b);
            imgOut=  (0.2126*Imgin[coord] + 0.7152*Imgin[coord+1] + 0.0722*Imgin[coord+2]) ;
            datau32 dataOutSideChannel;
            dataOutSideChannel.data = imgOut;
            outStream.write (dataOutSideChannel);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tools complains that it cannot deal with the binary operators in `imgOut= (0.2126*Imgin[coord] + 0.7152*Imgin[coord+1] + 0.0722*Imgin[coord+2])`.  Binary operators are operators with two operands, here `*` and `+`.  As mentioned in the error message, `datau32` is of type `ap_axiu<32, 2, 5, 6>`.  `Imgin` and `imgOut` have `datau32` as basetype.  Hence, the message appears to be referring to the multiplications of `Imgin[...]` with the floating-point constants (`0.2126`, etc.)

Anyway, `ap_axiu` is used to declare AXI buses.  It is a structure with the following format (See page 110 of UG902 for Vivado HLS 2017.1.):

```
template<int D,int U,int TI,int TD>
struct ap_axiu{
  ap_uint<D> data;
  ap_uint<D/8> keep;
  ap_uint<D/8> strb;
  ap_uint<U> user;
  ap_uint<1> last;
  ap_uint<TI> id;
  ap_uint<TD> dest;
};
```

So what you are trying to do is multiply a floating-point constant with a structure.  That is not allowed in C++.

If you did intent to use an AXI bus, you will have to use the `data` field of the structure to convey the data.  The result of multiplying the integer `data` field with a `double` is another `double`.  `double` is 64-bit wide, so you will have to handle that discrepancy too.  You could use constants of type `float`, which is likely enough precision.  Or you could make your AXI bus wider.  Or you could reduce the precision after the computation by casting to `float`.  Or you could use 2 bus cycles to transfer a single element.  Note that if you want to convert a `double` or `float` to an integer, you will have to use `reinterpret_cast` to avoid losing precision.  Note that you will also have to assign values to all other fields of the `ap_axiu` structure.  Note that you will also have to assign values to all other fields of the `ap_axiu` structure (`keep`, `strb`, etc.).

An easier way to use the AXI bus is by declaring `inStream` and `outStream` as arrays, e.g. `ap_uint<32> inStream[320*240]`.  The handshaking (`TREADY` and `TVALID`) is automatically taken care of.  If you need the so-called side-channel (the remaining signals like `TLAST` or `TUSER`), you cannot use this method.  That may be the case, for example, if you want to transmit packets of data instead of a continuous stream (can be done with `TLAST`), or if your data size is not a multiple of the bus size such that you need a byte enable signal (`TKEEP`).

I can also imagine that you never intended to use an AXI bus.  There are types such as `ap_uint` and `ap_fixed` that can be used to submit data on a plain bus.

Finally, I want to emphasize that **you should always debug your code in software first**.  There are many bugs that are hard to solve based on the output of the synthesis alone.  Some messages tend to point people in the wrong direction.  I recommend that you debug your code using the C simulation functionality first.  Alternatively, you can compile the code outside Vivado HLS with a regular C compiler such as `gcc`.  I also recommend using a memory checker such as `valgrind` to ensure that your code does not write outside array bounds, etc.  The tool does not always find these issues, but it does result in unusable hardware.

I think this is the solution that you are looking for:

```
void resize_half(ap_uint<32> inAXI[640 * 480 * 3], ap_uint<32> outAXI[320 * 240])
{
#pragma HLS INTERFACE axis port=inAXI
#pragma HLS INTERFACE axis port=outAXI
#pragma HLS INTERFACE s_axilite port=return bundle=CRTL_BUS

#pragma HLS dataflow
  hls::stream<ap_uint<32> > Stream[3];
  for (int i = 0; i < 480; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 640; j++)
      for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
      {
#pragma HLS PIPELINE II=1
        ap_uint<32> value = inAXI[3 * (640 * i + j) + k];
        if (i % 2 == 0 && j % 2 == 0)
          Stream[k].write(value);
      }

  for (int a = 0; a < 240; a++)
  {
    for (int b = 0; b < 320; b++)
    {
#pragma HLS PIPELINE II=1
      ap_uint<32> x = Stream[0].read();
      ap_uint<32> y = Stream[1].read();
      ap_uint<32> z = Stream[2].read();
      outAXI[320 * a + b] = 0.2126 * x + 0.7152 * y + 0.0722 * z;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I changed the line of code into Imgin.data and now it works. Also, I declare the floating point using ap_fixed.
Do you mean to use hls::stream<ap_uint<32>> inStream[640*480] ?

Comment: Most of my suggestions are different ways to achieve the same thing, so implementing all of them at the same time will probably not work. If you use `Imgin.data`, you should also set the other fields. Using `hls::stream<ap_uint<32>> inStream[640*480]` makes no sense. That way, you are declaring 640*480 streams. In combination with the `axis` interface, I suggest you use `ap_uint<32> inStream[640*480]` and stop using the `ap_axiu` structure.

Comment: I got what you mean, another question: I thought I must use stream interface if I want to use the DMA in Vivado IP Integrator later?

Comment: You can use an array or a `hls::stream` and set it as `axis` interface, but not both. Anyway, upon examining your code more closely, I noticed that you are trying to downconvert an image. You are essentially skipping samples, something the tool easily complains about. To help you a bit, I made an implementation that synthesizes, and I believe it should work, but I admit I haven't tested it properly. I put it at the end of my answer.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to resize and do grayscale conversion at the same time for an input image of 640*480. The output will be a grayscale image of 320*240. Thanks for the code. I'll try it out.